# jbpm & drools workbench vs eclipse. Why do both of these exist?

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat, jbpm

If workbench can achieve everything, then why do we have an eclipse plugin for development?

If workbench has the entire functionality right from defining rules to exposing restful apis, then eclipse would be redundant right?

Or am I missing something?

I am new to jbpm/drools and before proceeding, wanted to understand why both of them exist instead of just 1.

Answer (score 0):

JBPM/Drools can be used in standalone mode or embedded mode. In standalone mode, workbench seems to be the best way to create and manage rules and processes. In embedded mode, jbpm/drools is embedded into an existing project. In that case, it is good to have an eclipse plugin for jbpm/drools so that entire project can be developed in a single platform.

In my experience, even if you use workbench, you still have to develop some java classes(using an IDE) outside of workbench.

Moreover, it is up to developer to decide what suits better.